# How to use clang thread annotations with a RAII style try-lock?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, clang++

I would like to wrap the following code with clang thread annotations:

```cpp
std::mutex mutex;
int counter = 0; // should be accessed while the mutex is locked
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex, std::try_to_lock);
if (lock) {
   ++counter;
}
```

I want both to use a RAII lock (`std::unique_guard`) and I also would like to add thread annotations to this code.

```cpp
class __attribute__((capability("mutex"))) Mutex {
public:
    Mutex() = default;
    std::mutex &getInternalMutex() { return m_mutex; }
private:
    std::mutex m_mutex{};
};

class __attribute__((scoped_lockable)) TryLock {
public:
    TryLock(Mutex &mutex)
        // PROBLEM HERE: __attribute__((acquire_capability(mutex)))
        // is not suitable (lock may fail) but
        // __attribute__((try_acquire_capability(true, mutex)))
        // cannot be used neither (requires to be used in a method
        // returning whether the lock succeed or not)
        : m_try_lock(mutex.getInternalMutex(), std::try_to_lock) {}
    ~TryLock() __attribute__((release_capability)) = default;

    bool isLocked() const {
        return !!m_try_lock;
    }
private:
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> m_try_lock;
};
```

clang only provides `try_acquire_capability` which is not suitable here (as it should be used for a function returning a boolean indicating if the lock succeeded or not).

What would be the correct way to annotate this lock?